# Cordova doesn't send origin on request in some Android devices

Tags: android, cordova, cors, android-webview, cordova-plugins

This is a problem that happens on some android devices.

I have a `Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017)` with Google `Chrome version 76.0.3809.89` and Android version 8.0.0.

When I deploy my Cordova application for the first time on this device and making a POST request I receive an error about CORS:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://foo.com/bar' from origin 'file://' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I can saw from Chrome's dev tool network tab that this POST request, doesn't have the `origin` parameter.

If I close the application from the task manager and starting it again I can make this request successfully and chrome sends the 'origin' parameter on request.

I can re-produce the problem again if I delete applications' data from device's settings.

I'm totally sure that this is not a problem with `Content-Security-Policy` or `cordova-whitelist-plugin` configuration because as I mention before, on some other android devices the application works just fine.

Something other that I need to mention is that with crosswalk plugin I didn't have this problem.

Comment: Check [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107&q=cordova&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) bug. We are currently having this problem in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're experiencing the same issue. We first tried to implement a workaround where the App detects the Chrome version. The first time it sees version 76 it automatically restarts the app. Most users wouldn't even notice the restart. The workaround was based on several reports which stated, that the problem would only appear during the first run of the app after Chroe 76 had been installed and permanently disappear after a restart. However, it turned out, that the problem often returns seemingly randomly, so the woraround wasn't sufficient.

Luckily we're in control of the server side too, so we implemented a workaround there. Basicly we simply accept the `file://` origin. The security impact of this workaround certainly depends on the individual application, so think about it carefully in case you consider implemeinting something similar.

In our case we're using ASP.NET where we were facing an additional challenge. Unfortunately `EnableCorsAttribute` fails when specifying `file://` as an origin, which is in line with the CORS specification, which requires a hostname to be present in each origin (except when specifying `*`). So we finally came up with the following solution (specific to ASP.NET of course):

Create an `ICorsPolicyProvider` that overrides the validation logic in case of origin `file://` and delegates to a nested provider (the original one) in all other cases:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Object that allows clients with `file://` origin. This is used as a workaround
    /// for issues on Android devices running Chrome 76. See
    /// https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107#c14
    /// 
    /// Simply adding `file://` to the allowed origins list doesn't work, because by
    /// specification a hostname is required.
    /// 
    /// This workaround should be removed as soon as Chrome 76 distribution has dropped
    /// sufficiently.
    /// </summary>
    // TODO: Remove this workaround once Chrome 76 is not around anymore.
    public class CorsPolicyProviderAcceptingFileOrigin : ICorsPolicyProvider
    {
        public readonly ICorsPolicyProvider inner;

        public CorsPolicyProviderAcceptingFileOrigin(ICorsPolicyProvider inner)
        {
            this.inner = inner;
        }

        public async Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (
                request.Headers.TryGetValues("origin", out IEnumerable<string> origins)
                && origins.SequenceEqual(new[] { "file://" })
                )
            {
                var policy = new CorsPolicy()
                {
                    AllowAnyHeader = true,
                    AllowAnyMethod = true,
                    AllowAnyOrigin = false,
                };
                policy.Origins.Add("file://");

                return policy;
            }

            return await this.inner.GetCorsPolicyAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

and then use it like this in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```cs
// get the original EnableCorsAttribute
ICorsPolicyProvider cors = ...;

// this is a workaround for Android devices running Chrome 76 and should be removed in future versions.
// See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107
cors = new CorsPolicyProviderAcceptingFileOrigin(cors);

config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was having the same issue, but in apache.  Had to set CORS to allow all file://.  I am seriously questioning the value of CORS.  Seems to be all hassle and no benefit at all.

Comment: Well, this really is a problem of Chrome, not of CORS. CORS addresses some serious security aspects but I agree, that it's sometimes somewhat complex to get it right.

Comment: @markusm answer worked for me- but only after i add this line too:

policy.Origins.Add("null");

Answer (score 9):

This is an open bug on Chromium webview interesting the 76 version; in this specific version the OOR-CORS remains enabled in the first run.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107#c14

A change list will be merged to the 76 branch directly.

Answer (score 0):

We're experiencing the same issue... AJAX calls won't work after the first coldstart in our Cordova projects. If we restart the app (remove app from background) then it works... It appears to be a problem with the Chromium WebView version... I found a very ugly workaround. Use the

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#restart

plugin and restart the app after the first coldstart. Check in localStorage for a coldstart flag. If you don't find it restart the app.