# Cordova - XHR Requests on Android work in Emulator, but not on Phones

Tags: java, android, cordova, xmlhttprequest

so I have an existing app that has been on the app store for quite some time, as of 3 days ago I was getting more support enquiries saying my app could not connect to my service.

Now it has finally happened to me on my Android devices - everything works perfectly for iOS, and perfectly for Android on Emulator - but nothing in the real world.

I have looked as far as I can by step-debugging with Cordova and it passes the whitelist test fine. My very first XHR request works fine, but subsequent ones always fail until I completely close the app and re-open.

I am using `cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.3.4` - I have also tried `cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0`

My `Content-Security-Policy` looks like this

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' gap:; img-src http://*.my-site.com.au https://*.my-site.com.au https://*.my-site.com http://*.my-site.com https://*.googleusercontent.com http://*.googleapis.com  https://google.com https://*.google.com https://*.googleapis.com https://*.gstatic.com 'self' data:; style-src http://*.googleapis.com https://*.googleapis.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com http://*.googleapis.com http://maps.google.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com https://maps.google.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

My Cordova config has

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

I have tried adding/removing/replacing the above/every combination with `<access origin="*" />` but no luck.

My XHR response always looks like the following

```
xhr.responseUrl = "http://my-site.com/?d=12343902i49"
xhr.status = 0
xhr.responseText = ""
```

I have step-debugged the XHR request as far as I could have in the Cordova Plugin, by step debugging out of the `Whitelist.java` but everything returns fine and it makes it successfully to the line

```
// If we don't need to special-case the request, let the browser load it.
return null;
```

of function

```
WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)
```

in `org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewClient.java`

My Android Manifest has the following

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

I am using Cordova@8.0.0, Cordova platform Android@8.0.0

I've spent several hours trying to dig deeper, what am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the OS of the emulator and the OS of the device?

Comment: what is the XHR error log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the problem disappears if you lower the targetSDK, it's probably the `usesCleartextTraffic` mentioned by Nidhin Josehp. It only affects Android 8 or newer devices when targeting SDK 28 or greater.

Instead of manually editing the `AndroidManifest.xml` as he suggest (you should never manually edit it in Cordova apps) you can add this to the `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

You might need to change your widget tag in `config.xml` to look something like this:

```
<widget id="com.your.app.id" version="1.0.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

(The addition is the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`)

Comment: Very bizarre that this was the issue, I am using https so I am wondering what else would be the issue - anyway yes this does fix the problem.

Comment: Nice fix!  Spent hours digging on this one.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `<application>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` or as below using `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

> **android:usesCleartextTraffic** Indicates whether the app intends to use cleartext network traffic, such as cleartext HTTP. The default
>   value for apps that target API level 27 or lower is "true". Apps that
>   target API level 28 or higher default to "false". [More info](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)
>
> **Cleartext** is any transmitted or stored information that is not
>   encrypted or meant to be encrypted. When an app communicates with
>   servers using a cleartext network traffic, such as HTTP, it could
>   raise a risk of eavesdropping and tampering of content which is why in latest Android devices, it's set to `false` by default.

Comment: this worked for me. now i am at least getting a response from the server which i have logged into the console.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to jump I swear.

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />`

Changed targetSdkVersion to 26 from 28. Worked. But this is going to be a nightmare.

[image: But this is going to be a nightmare]

Edit: Problem has come back but only for Samsung Galaxy Tablets. I can't replicate this behaviour anywhere else.

Edit2: Things are...fine again?

Comment: Do you still want somebody to answer this or is your problem solved?

Comment: By the way, set your `targetSdkVersion` to 29. It's the latest

Comment: @GauravMall it is a bizarre one. The issue has remedied itself with no intervention (for a third time), we were just having issues with the Samsung Galaxy Tablet S2 and Samsung Note 9, I am beyond baffled and I am just going pray that there will be no more issues with it. All the other devices we tested on were working perfectly.

Comment: Could be a device only issue. I would advise using some kind of test lab(like firebase) to see if it is a general issue or a device-only one.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues sounds quite similar to what is discussed in [Cordova doesn't send origin on request in some Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326410/cordova-doesnt-send-origin-on-request-in-some-android-devices/57405841), which refers to a CORS-related issue caused by a bug introduced in Chrome 76 (WebViews based on the same version of WebKit are affected too). Chrome 76 started to be rolled out beginning of August 2019. The problem often disappears if the affected app is restarted but returns randomly.

The corresponding ticket is https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107. According to the ticket, the problem is fixed in Chrome 76.0.3809.111, which is being rolled out these days.

On your emulator you probably have an older version of Chrome, which might be the reason why the problem doesn't show up there. If you compare affected and unaffected devices and see, that only devices running Chrome in versions >= `76.0` and < `76.0.3809.111` show the symptoms, you probably found the cause of the problem.

If this is the case, you have at least these options:

- Wait util the fixed version of Chrome has been rolled out (which might the case already for many affected phones).
- If you're in control of the server, you could add the `file://` origin to [the list of allowed origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) there, [which is what we did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57405841/2833040). You have to think about the security implications carefully though.

Btw, after restarting the app, the issue most often disappeared, which makes it hard to debug. We found out, that it can be reproduced by uninstalling and reinstalling the affected app.

Comment: @DoD Could you find out, whether the problem only appears on devices running Chrome 76 (or corresponding WebKit-based WebView)? I added info on how to reproduce the issue (by reinstalling the app). 

Btw, the most official reference to the issue you will find probably is https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107.

Comment: It fixed itself which I am really confused about. That does not make sense. I haven't had a single complaint from clients about it anymore.

Comment: Well, that's probably a good indication, that this is the answer to your question. The problem was probably fixed with _Chrome 76.0.3809.111_, [which was released on Aug 9th](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2019/08/chrome-for-android-update.html) and subsequently rolled out thereafter. As soon as clients received the new Chrome version, the issue was gone.